_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Good day everyone,
I have an issue when i try to use _api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail at SP2019 and shows this message:
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}

when I check the console I found this message:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Site-Url/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail

I don't know what makes this API method not working and giving 404 not found.
